# Dictionary of Dictionaries of Dictionaries of Dictionaries syntax understanding

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to map the doors of buildings into a single map, from which afterward I need to populate three pickers using this data.

Each door contains the following data: building, level, range, door number and other information that is less relevant. So I created the following map:

```
public var doorsMap: [String : [String : [String : [String: Door]]]] = [:]
```

and a have a list of doors that I need to populate this map with, the problem is that I can't understand what should be the right syntax to perform this task, I tried:

```
doorsMap[door.building]?[door.level]?[door.range]?[door.number] = door
```

but this doesn't create the inner sets of dictionaries. when I tried to do:

```
doorsMap[door.building]![door.level]![door.range]![door.number] = door
```

Obviously, I get the:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

because I try to unwrap a nil value.

So what would be the correct syntax in swift to populate this map from a list of doors?

Comment: @Cristik I didn't expect not to crush, on the contrary, I just stated what I tried and what was the results of my tries.

Comment: If the intermediate dictionaries don't exist then you need to create them explicitly.  A single assignment won't create multiple dictionaries. All of that force unwrapping is bad too. If a door must have, say, a level, why is the `level` property optional?

Comment: Well... you shouldn't try 3 levels of forced unwraps, plus the forced unwraps of the keys...

Comment: I rephrased the question a bit, I guess it more clear now.

Comment: @Paulw11, it's optional because I get this data from the server and until I get it it doesn't have a value. Yes, i do understand the force unwrapping is bad and it's not the way to go. but the question mark unwrapping didn't work either so I tried it.

Comment: But your shouldn't create a `Door` instance until you have all of the data, so the property doesn't need to be optional.

Comment: You are encouraged to use custom structs rather then generic dictionaries. It makes things much easier.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes you are right, ignore the fact that I'm force unwrapping the inner data of the door this is my mistake, but it has nothing to do with the question. i will remove it from the question.

Comment: @vadian, could you care to elaborate a bit more? will this still give me O(1) reads of the data?

Comment: @EmilAdz you might be suffering from the premature optimization symptom :)

Comment: Why dictionaries? Would it not be much better to create a data structure using structs to model this?

Comment: As @Paulw11 said you have to explicitly create each dictionary, they will not be automatically created for you. However, when you do that you may find that your code performance is abysmal. Avoid deeply nested collections in Swift like a plague. The fact they are value types will give you much grief.

Comment: @Cristik, no I just have a requirement that I need to follow, and even more, I think that I have a bit a curiosity about how this should be performed... because I think that a new and advanced version of the language should give me a simple syntax to handle this task.

Comment: @EmilAdz such a feature exists, it's called `Decodable` ;)

Comment: @Cristik, would you mind to elaborate how Decodable helps me? For what I know decodable is used to parse JSON into objects, or am I wrong?

Comment: @EmilAdz `Decodable` can be used to parse any format, not only JSON. It's a protocol, afterall ;) I can't give you a concrete answer on how to use `Decodable` for your question as you only provided a subset of the details of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single assignment won't create the multiple, intermediate directories.  You need to do it explicitly.

You could use something like this:

```
func add(door: Door) {
    var building = self.doorsMap[door.building] ?? [String : [String:[String: Door]]]()
    var level = building[door.level] ?? [String : [String: Door]]()
    var range = level[door.range] ?? [String:Door]
    range[door.number] = door
    level[door.range] = range
    building[door.level] = level
    self.doorsMap[door.building] = building
}
```

Personally, I would look for a better data structure, perhaps use a struct to hold the `doorsMap`.  This struct could have functions to handle the insertion and retrieval of doors.

Perhaps something like this:

```
struct Door {
    let building: String
    let level: String
    let range: String
    let number: String
}

struct DoorMap {
    private var buildingsSet = Set<String>()
    private var levelsSet = Set<String>()
    private var rangesSet = Set<String>()
    private var numberSet = Set<String>()
    private var doorsArray = [Door]()

    var buildings: [String] {
        get {
            return Array(buildingsSet).sorted()
        }
    }

    var levels: [String] {
        get {
            return Array(levelsSet).sorted()
        }
    }

    var ranges: [String] {
        get {
            return Array(rangesSet).sorted()
        }
    }

    var numbers: [String] {
        get {
            return Array(numberSet).sorted()
        }
    }

    var doors: [Door] {
        get {
            return doorsArray
        }
    }

    mutating func add(door: Door) {
        buildingsSet.insert(door.building)
        levelsSet.insert(door.level)
        rangesSet.insert(door.range)
        numberSet.insert(door.number)
        doorsArray.append(door)
    }

    func doorsMatching(building: String? = nil, level: String? = nil, range: String? = nil, number: String? = nil) -> [Door]{

        let matches = doorsArray.filter { (potentialDoor) -> Bool in
            var included = true
            if let b = building {
                if potentialDoor.building != b {
                    included = false
                }
            }

            if let l = level {
                if potentialDoor.level != l {
                    included = false
                }
            }

            if let r = range {
                if potentialDoor.range != r {
                    included = false
                }
            }

            if let n = number {
                if potentialDoor.number != n {
                    included = false
                }
            }

            return included
        }

        return matches

    }
}

var map = DoorMap()

let d1 = Door(building: "b1", level: "1", range: "r1", number: "1")
let d2 = Door(building: "b1", level: "2", range: "r1", number: "2")
let d3 = Door(building: "b2", level: "2", range: "r1", number: "2")
map.add(door: d1)
map.add(door: d2)
map.add(door: d3)

let b1Doors = map.doorsMatching(building:"b1")
let level2Doors = map.doorsMatching(level:"2")
let allBuildings = map.buildings()
```

Now, maybe you have more information on buildings and levels etc, so they could be structs too instead of just strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. would you mind to elaborate more on the struct proposal? you mean to create a class that will hold all this data?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed second option. I will suggest it tomorrow and see if they go for it.